# How do I get the HTML code from a website and into a string for VB?

Tags: html, vb.net, web-scraping, webclient

I know that this will store the **page source** in the variable *HTML*.

```
Dim Client As New WebClient
URL = Console.Readline
HTML = Client.DownloadString(New Uri(URL))
```

But doing this doesn't save absolutely every element from the website, for example some URL links and videos can't be seen either.

How do I get **all** pages elements from a page into a string variable?

Thanks

Comment: You cannot use a WebClient or HttpClient (or WebRequest directly) to download the content of pages that are generated/filled by scripts. You need to use a WebBrowser class (class, not control), Navigate to the URL, use the `DocumentCompleted` event along `[WebBrowser].ReadyState != WebBrowserReadyState.Complete` to verify whether the Html Document has been rendered completely, then get the `[WebBrowser].Document` object and use its method (`GetElementById`, `GetElementsByTagName` etc.) to extract the values of specific HtmlElements.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following code in your program:

```
Console.Write("Input the site URL: ")
Dim URL As String = Console.ReadLine()

Console.WriteLine(New Net.WebClient().DownloadString(URL))
Console.ReadKey() ' to wait for user exit
```

Enjoy!

[image: Web Scraper]

Comment: Sorry, this wasn't what I was looking for. I can't tell if it outputting anything different. I am trying to extract a link from the HTML code which shows up when I Inspect Element on the website but the link doesn't show up when I use this code or the code I showed in the question.

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim request As HttpWebRequest = TryCast(WebRequest.Create("https://google.com/"), HttpWebRequest)
Dim response As HttpWebResponse = TryCast(request.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse)
Dim dataStream As Stream = response.GetResponseStream()
Dim reader As New StreamReader(dataStream)
Dim responseFromServer As String = reader.ReadToEnd()
reader.Close()
response.Close()

'Use responseFromServer to see the Full Source Code of the Html Page
```

Comment: I am getting the errors: "Type 'Stream' is not defined." and "Type 'StreamReader' is not defined". Did I forgot to do something? EDIT: I realised I need "IO." before them. Also, I am sorry to say but this code isn't what I am looking for, it does the same thing as my code.

Comment: Imports System.Io

Comment: If it dosnt show the Full Source code you will need to work with Cookies for example read the Source Code of a Login Next Page.